# Issue With Code: Format string is not a string literal

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SnowLeopard Xcode warning: “format not a string literal and no format arguments”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677824/snowleopard-xcode-warning-format-not-a-string-literal-and-no-format-arguments)

I am getting the following issue for this line of code.

"Format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)"

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", entered]);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey Faisal, Actually this is because you have not written the `@"%@"`, string specifier under the NSLog Statement. Just check out my answer. Hope that helps you. :)

Comment: @Parth Old thread, good help, but why not as an answer already?

Comment: NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", entered], nil);

Answer (score 140, accepted):

The compiler wants us to use an NSString constant for the format string (the first argument to `NSLog`) because it prevents a fairly well-known exploit that could potentially violate security. So for example, you could change the code you posted as follows to keep the compiler happy:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", entered]);
```

**EDIT**

And of course, the above could (and should) simply be written as follows:

```
NSLog(@"%@", entered);
```

**Nature of Security Exploits**

> **Uncontrolled format string**[1] is a type of software vulnerability,
>   discovered around 1999, that can be used in security exploits.
>   Previously thought harmless, format string exploits can be used to
>   crash a program or to execute harmful code. The problem stems from the
>   use of unchecked user input as the format string parameter in certain
>   C functions that perform formatting, such as `printf()`. A malicious
>   user may use the `%s` and `%x` format tokens, among others, to print data
>   from the stack or possibly other locations in memory. One may also
>   write arbitrary data to arbitrary locations using the `%n` format token,
>   which commands `printf()` and similar functions to write the number of
>   bytes formatted to an address stored on the stack.
>
> A typical exploit
>   uses a combination of these techniques to force a program to overwrite
>   the address of a library function or the return address on the stack
>   with a pointer to some malicious shellcode. The padding parameters to
>   format specifiers are used to control the number of bytes output and
>   the `%x` token is used to pop bytes from the stack until the beginning
>   of the format string itself is reached. The start of the format string
>   is crafted to contain the address that the `%n` format token can then
>   overwrite with the address of the malicious code to execute.

Source: Wikipedia [Uncontrolled Format String](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string)

[1]: http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/134.html "CWE-134: Uncontrolled Format String". Common Weakness Enumeration. MITRE.

Comment: Could you show how this "well-known" exploit works?

Comment: +1 for **Nature of Security Exploits**

Comment: +1 for how does this solution prevent "the use of unchecked user input as the format string parameter in certain C functions that perform formatting"

Answer (score 31):

Here is the solution.

[Warning: "format not a string literal and no format arguments"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677824/snowleopard-xcode-warning-format-not-a-string-literal-and-no-format-arguments)

Try with

```
NSLog(@"%@",entered);
```

because NSLog can also do formatting for you...

Comment: This is a better answer than the one that was accepted. There's no need to use stringWithFormat: when NSLog() already uses a format!

Answer (score 2):

**Try:**

```
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",entered]);
```

Hope this helps you. :)