# Printing a Variable in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to print the word that is being "spoken" by this app onto the console so I can store it in a variable for later use. The function is like so and I am trying to print the content within the variable "word". How would I go about this?

```
- (void)speak:(NSString *)words {
  if ([synth isSpeaking]) {
      NSLog(words);
    return;
  }
  AVSpeechUtterance *utterance =
      [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:words];
  utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-US"];
  utterance.rate = 0.75 * AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate;
  [synth speakUtterance:utterance];

}
```

I have tried to add the NSLog(words) in there, as I thought that would be the way to approach this. However, I get an error and that does not work. I have added it in the code block above just for clarity in what I have done.

Comment: use `- (void)speak:(NSString *)words {
    
    NSLog(@"%@", words);
}`

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", words);

Comment: Please, when posting a question about an error, please include the complete and exact error in your question and point out the exact line causing the error.

Comment: @rmaddy my apologies. The error happens in line 3 - NSLog(words) and it says "Format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)"

Comment: Please see the @NehaGupta comment. This is correct format of NSLog

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799731/warning-format-string-is-not-a-string-literal-potentially-insecure

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"words :: %@", words);
```

or

in console tab print

```
 po words
```

Comment: Please take the time to post proper code. Objective-C is case-sensitive.

Comment: is not `nslog` it is `NSLog`