# Rcpp warning: format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)

Tags: string, rcpp, cran, rcpparmadillo

Recently I have received the following error message on CRAN for some of my packages.

```
warning: format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)
```

See for example the following [link](https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/R.check/r-devel-linux-x86_64-debian-clang/hpa-00check.html) for the exact error messages (there are many other packages on CRAN which have received this error message recently).

Unfortunatelly I am not able to reproduce this error and can't find its source. My hypothesis is that this error is somehow related to `stop()` function since I do not use strings in other parts of Rcpp code. Also errors refer to the parts of RcppExports.cpp files which are looking like this:

```
Rboolean rcpp_isError_gen = Rf_inherits(rcpp_result_gen, "try-error");
if (rcpp_isError_gen) {
    SEXP rcpp_msgSEXP_gen = Rf_asChar(rcpp_result_gen);
    UNPROTECT(1);
    Rf_error(CHAR(rcpp_msgSEXP_gen));
}
```

But it seems that there is nothing special about my strings so I can't figure out how to fix the issue. My calls to `stop()` function look like:

```
  if (degree <= 0)
  {
    stop("degree should be positive integer");
  }
```

So I use no special formatting which may cause such issues according to the answers to this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799731/warning-format-string-is-not-a-string-literal-potentially-insecure) question. Please, help me figure out this error message.

Will be very greatful for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see the extended discussion at the repository in issue #1287 and PR #1288 ie [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/1287) especially the [comment](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/1287#issuecomment-1829886024) as well as the [extended post on the rcpp-devel list](https://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/rcpp-devel/2023-November/010901.html) I also made today.

In short, you need an updated `Rcpp` version installed (instructions given) and then use it to update your `RcppExports.cpp`. Once that is done you can upload the updated version of your package under an increased version number.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! I will try it!

Comment: Pleasure!  As usual, feel free to accept the answer if it suits.