# Rcpp Rf_warningcall compiler warnings

Tags: r, clang, rcpp

In the C++ code of the R/terra package I using the below to handle warnings:

```
template <typename... Args>
inline void warningNoCall(const char* fmt, Args&&... args ) {
    Rf_warningcall(R_NilValue, tfm::format(fmt, std::forward<Args>(args)... ).c_str());
}
```

See https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/03/suppressing-call-stack-info-in-rcpp-generated-errors-and-warnings/

That works fine, but CRAN now asks me to fix it because of CLANG compiler warnings.

```
Found the following significant warnings:
    RcppFunctions.cpp:298:32: warning: format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure) [-Wformat-security]
    ./geos_spat.h:80:32: warning: format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure) [-Wformat-security]
  See ‘/home/hornik/tmp/R.check/r-devel-clang/Work/PKGS/terra.Rcheck/00install.out’ for details.
```

This has been fixed Rcpp code generated by `compileAttributes()` (see https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/1287), but that is not the case here. (This is not generated by `compileAttributes`.)

How can I adjust the code above to avoid this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may have seen [first in the respective GitHub issue #1287](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/1287) or second [here in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77567312/rcpp-warning-format-string-is-not-a-string-literal-potentially-insecure/) or then [in my summary answer on the Rcpp list](https://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/rcpp-devel/2023-November/010901.html), these new warnings from R-devel and `g++` / `clang++` under `-Wformat -Wformat-security` have gotten to a few people.

In most cases this is simple. In your case it is a little different per your code conventions but I think you want

```
template <typename... Args>
inline void warningNoCall(const char* fmt, Args&&... args ) {
    Rf_warningcall(R_NilValue, "%s", tfm::format(fmt, std::forward<Args>(args)... ).c_str());
}
```

matching what I now have in Rcpp itself with a format string as the second argument:

```
inline void warningcall(SEXP call, const std::string & s) {
    Rf_warningcall(call, "%s", s.c_str());
}
```

(I think you could also try

```
template <typename... Args>
inline void warningNoCall(const char* fmt, Args&&... args ) {
    ::Rf_warning("%s", tfm::format(fmt, std::forward<Args>(args)... ).c_str());
}
```

if the caller is of no concern to you.  But this is untested.)