# getting a warning "Format string is not a String litral(Potentially insecure)"

Tags: ios, nsstring

When I'm using this line of code :

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]]);
```

I get the following warning :

> Format string is not a String litral(Potentially insecure)"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue With Code: Format string is not a string literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428325/issue-with-code-format-string-is-not-a-string-literal)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an `NSString` constant as first parameter of `NSLog` in order to avoid exploits. Change your code to :

```
NSLog(@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]);
```

The exploit is more  explained on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428325/issue-with-code-format-string-is-not-a-string-literal).