# Warning message when launch a map by UIApplication sharedApplication

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, dictionary

I link the following openMap method to a button. The method does work but there is an error message at

```
NSLog(urlText);
```

The message shows **format string is not a literal (potentially insecure)**.
Does anyone know how to eliminate this warning?

```
-(IBAction)openMap:(id)sender{
    NSString* addressText = @"New York";
    addressText =  [addressText stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString* urlText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%@", addressText];
    NSLog(urlText);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlText]];
}
```

Comment: The question you have asked in your body is totally different from the question title. Please make sure you change the question title for correct future reference. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: "format not a string literal and no format arguments"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677824/)

Comment: Sorry! Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the *NSLog* to,

```
NSLog(@"%@", urlText);
```

Or, remove the *NSLog* completely ;-)