# format not a string literal and no format arguments objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

When I build the below code, I get a warning like "Format not a string literal and no format arguments".

```
NSString *items = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",itemNumber[0]];

for (int i = 1; i < (_housesOwned[0] + 1); i++)
{
    items = [items stringByAppendingFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@",%d", itemNumber[i]]];
}
```

I'm getting the warning in the line inside for loop.

itemNumber is an int array. Please help. Even though build is successful, I'm having a feeling like this could mess up in future.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: "format not a string literal and no format arguments"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677824/warning-format-not-a-string-literal-and-no-format-arguments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make this line

```
items = [items stringByAppendingFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@",%d", itemNumber[i]]];
```

to

```
items = [items stringByAppendingFormat:@",%d", itemNumber[i]];
```

or

```
items = [items stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@",%d", itemNumber[i]]];
```

This will not give warning. Nothing else.