# stringWithFormat: Format string not a string literal

Tags: objective-c

I've come across a rather weird issue with `stringWithFormat:`. I create a string and assign it to an alert panel.

For some reason though, Xcode says that the format string isn't a string literal even though it is? Can anyone shed some light?

[image]

Header declaration:

```
APPKIT_EXTERN void NSBeginCriticalAlertSheet(NSString *title, NSString *defaultButton, NSString *alternateButton, NSString *otherButton, NSWindow *docWindow, id modalDelegate, SEL didEndSelector, SEL didDismissSelector, void *contextInfo, NSString *msgFormat, ...) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(10,11);
```

**Edit:** Looking at the header declaration, it came to me. I was missing a `nil` after the `msgFormat` variable. Xcode's warning was confusing though - it should have been `missing sentinel in function call` instead.

Comment: instead of screenshot paste your code here, it will be easier for us to use your code and check.

Comment: What's the difference? The code won't show the warning.

Comment: we can copy your code and paste in our IDE and compile, edit, correct. Otherwise we have to type exact code.... if we are not master to say only by seeing your code.

Comment: Also, mind if you show us the header declaration for `NSBeginCriticalAlertSheet()`?

Comment: @Anoop `_dev.name` originates from a custom object that you don't have, so copying/pasting will not work. @TheAmateurProgrammer It's defined in Panel.h. See edit for declaration.

Comment: Post it as an answer so others will know you solved it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you try to pass a `NSString` with a paramater inside a method that does the same. So the `NSBeginCriticalAlertSheet` is actually looking for another parameter.

If you put it in another `NSString stringWithFormat:` it takes the literal string instead of trying to parse it.

So in your `NSBeginCriticalAlertSheet`: `_warning` should be replaced with

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _warning]
```

Also see [warning-format-not-a-string-literal-and-no-format-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677824/warning-format-not-a-string-literal-and-no-format-arguments) for more information.

Comment: Actually, I was simply missing a `nil` at the end. :) See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 NSString *localizedStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bla bla %@ bla bla",_dev.name];
    NSString *_warning = NSLocalizedString(localizedStr);

    /*code for alert sheet
```

Comment: That confuses the `NSLocalizedString` macro defined in `Bundle.h` and causes an error.