# How to do NSLog with variable

Tags: objective-c

What should be the correct format of the below to print `*newString` ?

```
NSString *newString = @"Hello this is a string!";
NSLog(@newString);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@` symbol is just a shorthand for specifying some common Objective-C objects. `@"..."` represents a string (`NSString` to be specific, which is different from regular C strings), `@[...]` represents an array (`NSArray`), `@{...}` represents a dictionary (`NSDictionary`).

On the first line, you've already specified a `NSString` object using the `@` sign. `newString` is now an `NSString` instance. <strike>On the second line, you can just give it's variable name:</strike>

`NSLog(newString);`

You *could* theoretically just give the variable name, but it is a dangerous approach. If `newString` has any format specifiers, your app may crash/mess up (or access something that it shouldn't be accesing) because `NSLog` would try to read the arguments corresponding to the format specifiers, but the arguments don't exist. The safe solution would be `NSLog(@"%@", newString);`. The first argument to `NSLog` is now hard-coded and can't be changed. We now know that it will expect a single argument, that we are providing that argument, `newString`, so we are safe.

Because you've already specified a string and just passing that instance to `NSLog`, you don't need the `@` sign again.

Comment: This is potentially insecure and you shouldn't get in this habit.  `NSLog(@"%@", newString);` is correct.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string.

Comment: wouldn't NSLOG handle this? it doesn't accept regular C strings anyway, you need to provide an NSString, which should be controlled anyway.

Comment: What if `newString` were @"%@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@".  **BOOM** is what.

Answer (score 3):

`NSLog` works pretty much as a C `printf`, with the addition of the `%@` string format specifier, which is meant for objects. Being `NSString` an object, `%@` is the right format to use:

```
NSString *newString = @"Hello this is a string!";
NSLog(@"%@", newString);
```

For as tempting as it can look, **NEVER** do

```
NSLog(newString); //NONONONONO!
```

since it's a terrible practice that may lead to unexpected crashes (not to mention security issues).

More info on the subject: [Warning: "format not a string literal and no format arguments"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677824/warning-format-not-a-string-literal-and-no-format-arguments)