# NSArray contains nothing after method call

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm calling a method passing two arrays to it as follow :

```
NSArray *marked_dates = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[dateFormat dateFromString:@"19/03/2014"],[dateFormat dateFromString:@"17/04/2014"],[dateFormat dateFromString:@"12/02/2014"], nil];
NSArray *marked_colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor greenColor],[UIColor greenColor],[UIColor greenColor],nil];
[calendar markDates:marked_dates withColors:marked_colors];
```

Below is the method receiving this :

```
-(void)markDates:(NSArray *)dates withColors:(NSArray *)colors {
    self.markedDates = dates;
    self.markedColors = colors;

    NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[dates count]]);

    for (int i = 0; i<[self.markedDates count]; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.markedDates[i]]);
    }

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

The log says 0 and I obviously don't get into the `for` loop.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT :
I will also vote up for any information about the warning : "format string is not a string literal"

Below the declaration of the properties :

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *markedDates;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *markedColors;
```

EDIT :

So yes, the formater gives null values.
Here is how I did it :

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormat dateFromString:@"19/03/2014"]]);
//this prints "null"
```

EDIT with solution :

Bad mistake, I misconfigured the formatter 
using this worked for me, thank you all for your help.

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
```

Comment: are both arrays you pass empty? have you once logged the arrays before sending them in the method call? Maybe the date formatter doesn't produce dates but nil...

Comment: Can you show the declaration of the `markedDates` and `markedColors` properties.

Comment: show the code on how you created the formatter `dateFormat`.

Comment: Probably your `[dateFormat dateFromString:@"19/03/2014"]` is returning nil. So `marked_dates` is nil.

Comment: Log marked_dates after it is created and see if it is empty or has some data

Comment: re format string is not a literal see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677824/warning-format-not-a-string-literal-and-no-format-arguments ;

Comment: You have MM/dd/yyyy, and your input is dd/MM/yyyy format.

Comment: use `NSLog("%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormat dateFromString:@"19/03/2014"]]);`

Comment: and 1 more thing. It seems that you are converting the `NSString` values  into `NSDate`, and reconverting them to `NSString` in `markDates:withColors:`. If it is used just for the sake of printing, then why do the conversion to `NSDate` in the first place?

Comment: @GoGreen it was just for logging yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dates array is probably empty due to the date formatter only producing `nil` values. Fix the date formatter so it will correctly generate `NSDate` objects and it should work:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"]; ?
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not create the property name and Local instance variable as same name. Because property it's self create instance var with _Property name.And the issue is with line.

```
NSArray *marked_dates = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[dateFormat dateFromString:@"19/03/2014"],[dateFormat dateFromString:@"17/04/2014"],[dateFormat dateFromString:@"12/02/2014"], nil];
```

Add the date format also.
check this again. let me know if you still facing the same issue.