# NSLog warning format string is not a string literal

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to log the segue identifier for debugging purpose.

I tried this:

```
NSString * string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test %@", segue.identifier];
        NSLog(string);
```

and I tried this:

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"test %@", segue.identifier]);
```

In both ways, Xcode shows a warning message states that `format string is not a string literal`

Why it is not string? I checked the `segue.identifier` property and it is from type `NSString *`

I am using Xcode 5.0.2 on OS 10.9

I appreciate your help.

Regards,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677824/warning-format-not-a-string-literal-and-no-format-arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use/try this

```
NSString * string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test %@",segue.identifier];

NSLog(@"your seque identifier is ==%@",string);
```